# GeoTools: Geo Transform incorrect

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, proj, transform

I am transforming a coordinate between Lambert Conformal and WGS84. The values returned by GeoTools do not seem correct.

From:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
        DATUM["unnamed",
            SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",50],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-105],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",50],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",20],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Metre",1],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

To:

```
EPSG:4326
```

When I transform the point -2133754.9447882758 1556902.2763524954 I get differing results between proj4 and GeoTools.

Proj4:    -141.538155   60.069556
Geotools: -141.538155   60.235687

As I move toward the equator, the difference in latitude of the transformed point approaches zero. Looks like a datum shift error. I have reason to believe that the proj4 transform is correct as the raster data I am working with is defined with the lambert conformal CRS shown above. When I warp to epsg:4326 with GDAL, the result is correct. When I warp using geotools, the resulting image is shifted north progressively from the equator northward. Any thoughts as to why geotools is incorrect?

```
echo -2133754.9447882758 1556902.2763524954 | cs2cs -f "%f" +proj=lcc +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-105 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=20 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371229 +units=m +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326
-141.538155 60.069556 0.000000
```

Geotools code to transform a point v26.3:

```
        String wktLC = "PROJCS[\"unnamed\",\n" +
                "    GEOGCS[\"Coordinate System imported from GRIB file\",\n" +
                "        DATUM[\"unnamed\",\n" +
                "            SPHEROID[\"Sphere\",6371229,0]],\n" +
                "        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],\n" +
                "        UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n" +
                "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]]],\n" +
                "    PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP\"],\n" +
                "    PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",50],\n" +
                "    PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-105],\n" +
                "    PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",50],\n" +
                "    PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",20],\n" +
                "    PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],\n" +
                "    PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],\n" +
                "    UNIT[\"Metre\",1],\n" +
                "    AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],\n" +
                "    AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH]]";

        crsLCGraf = CRS.parseWKT(wktLC);
        crsWGS84 = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

        CoordinateReferenceSystem from = CRS.parseWKT(wktLC);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem to = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

        WKTReader reader = new WKTReader(new GeometryFactory());
        Geometry point = reader.read("POINT (-2133754.9447882758 1556902.2763524954)");

        MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(from, to, true);

        Point p2 = (Point) JTS.transform(point, transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact you have to set the `lenient` flag in the transform is probably the problem, this is giving you the transform:

```
CONCAT_MT[INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP", 
      PARAMETER["semi_major", 6371229.0], 
      PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6371229.0], 
      PARAMETER["central_meridian", -105.0], 
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 50.0], 
      PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1", 50.0], 
      PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
      PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
      PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
      PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2", 20.0]]], 
  PARAM_MT["Molodenski", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["dx", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["dy", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["dz", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["src_semi_major", 6371229.0], 
    PARAMETER["src_semi_minor", 6371229.0], 
    PARAMETER["tgt_semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["tgt_semi_minor", 6356752.314245179]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

I can't work out how to convince `cs2cs` to print out it's transform but I suspect that it is picking up a grid transform from somewhere which gives a different (more accurate?) answer.

Comment: Forgive me, I don't understand the details of how geotools performs the transforms from one CRS to another. If I set the lenient flag to false, I get an error that Bursa wolf parameters are required. Adding TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0] removes the error, but the transform result is the same (as expected I suppose). Shouldn't the datums described in the WKT above and the datum described in EPSG:4326 be enough for the transform...including the datum transform to be as precise as possible.

Comment: I suspect that cs2cs (and proj in general) is picking some other value for TOWGS84 but I don't know.